# AndroidManifest merge error using FileProvider

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm trying to use a library that has this in its AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.imagepicker.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

I have the same tag in my app's AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="@string/FileProviderAuthority"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

So it obviously gives a Manifest merger error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

Which suggests to "add 'tools:replace="android:authorities"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml to override".

So I add `tools:replace="android:authorities"` like this, in my app's AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    tools:replace="android:authorities"
    android:name=".appcontroller.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

And then I get this error:

```
Error:
tools:replace specified at line:25 for attribute android:authorities, but no new value specified
```

The same happens with `tools:replace="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 49):

To solve this there are two options: either you change your manifest to use a different class than `android.support.v4.content.FileProvider` or you create a PR/issue asking the owner of the lib to change his/hers (that would be the best case scenario).

If you want a quick fix, just create a class that extends `FileProvider` such as:

```
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;

public class MyFileProvider extends FileProvider {
}
```

and in your manifest file you change it to:

```
<provider android:name=".MyFileProvider" ... >
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!

Comment: `FileProvider` should be extended in order to override any of the default behavior, not to fix name collision.

Answer (score 31):

Add to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, inside the `application` tag:

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:replace="android:authorities">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"
            tools:replace="android:resource" />
    </provider>
```

Comment: This answer works for me. Do you know how/why this fixes the "manifest merger" issue?

Answer (score 10):

For those using sdk 28 and up, if you are migrating to androidx, solution is :

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
    tools:replace="android:authorities">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
</provider>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not change any of the values in the provider, you do not need to include it in your manifest. Just remove those lines.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick fix**: create a class that extends `androidx.core.content.FileProvider` as follows:

```
package com.example.mystuff;

import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;

public class MyFileProvider extends FileProvider {
}
```

and in your manifest file you change it to:

```
<provider android:name="com.example.mystuff.MyFileProvider" ... >
```

**Note**: same as douglas.iacovelli's answer with the path for FileProvider fixed (for SDK versions 33 & above)