# Error extending FileProvider

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-fileprovider

I need to use 2 file providers for my app.

I have tried the quick fix suggested in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42989182/7952427

But the app crashes.

I know that the second provider is causing this exception/crash because when i remove it, the app doesn't crash anymore.

In Manifest:

```
<provider
  android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.fileproviderTestLyb"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
        </meta-data>
    </provider>
    <provider
        android:name=".MyFileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider2"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS_video"
            android:resource="@xml/video_path">
        </meta-data>
    </provider>
```

The File Provider class:

```
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
public class MyFileProvider  extends FileProvider{
}
```

Can anyone help me understand why?
Do i need to add something to MyFileProvider class?

Comment: "And i'm getting this exception" -- are you sure that is coming from your process, and is not just some other stack trace from some other app that is showing up in LogCat? `FileProvider` has nothing to do with windows.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm new to Android, sorry :/  I've edited my question.

Comment: Well, if your app is crashing, there will be a stack trace for that crash in LogCat. It just has to be one from a process associated with what's going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS_video
```

with:

```
android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS
```

`FileProvider` will definitely crash if you do not provide a `android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS` `<meta-data>` element.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! I've accepted your answer but it doesn't show because i have less than 15 reputation.