# Should I get the same result from tesseract in Android and PC?

Tags: android, tesseract

I am trying to use tesseract on android, but the result is very bad. When I try it on Linux, I get very better result on the same papers. Is this normal or my android codes are wrong?(I will put my codes if needed)

**Also have other question, are `.traineddata` files different respect to PC or android version of tesseract?

Comment: Yes, results should be the same if input *images* are the same. Check that you are using same tesseract version (3.* is stable, 4.0 is alpha) and same traineddata files (tesseract 3 and 4 do require different traineddata files, you can find them in their [repository](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/)).

Comment: You didn't say whether you're using the camera to do the image capture on your Android device, or you're directly opening the image file.

Comment: @DmitriiZ.: I checked again and found that my tesseract version on Linux is 4 and in Android is 3.05(tess-two). I have very very nice recognition on Linux but very bad(actually not even 1 word) result onAndroid. I don't know is this huge difference normal or not?

Comment: @rmtheis: Dear rmtheis, I think you are the writer of `tess-two`, thank you for that, but it seems it doesn't work on Android. I tested it for both Persian and English languages, together and separately but it didn't work(0% true recognition). I use my phone's camera, but before using tesseract, I save the taken image, then pass it to tesseract. Then I tested that saved image with tesseract 4 on Linux. The results are not comparable! The Android code I used is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48990967/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-pictures-picfolde