# android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/image.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()

Tags: java, android

I am trying to open the phone's camera app using the app I am building. But I am getting the below error.

I have tried solving using the steps mentioned here : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48990967/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-pictures-picfolde][1]

But **android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"** is showing in red.

I tried to add the dependency : **compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'** but it is no longer supported.

My minSdkversion is 21 and targetSdkversion is 30.

Below is my code for opening camera:

```
private void capturePhoto() {

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    String imageName = "image.jpg";
    mImageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), imageName)); //result stored in  mImageUri
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);


}
```

Error message:

```
2022-03-06 18:41:02.551 3039-3039/com.beproject.sharepixel E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.beproject.sharepixel, PID: 3039
    android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/image.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
        at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1796)
        at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2346)
        at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:845)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8947)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8932)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1517)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4285)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:597)
        at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:237)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$2.onLaunch(ComponentActivity.java:210)
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$3.launch(ActivityResultRegistry.java:226)
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher.launch(ActivityResultLauncher.java:47)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.launchStartActivityForResult(FragmentManager.java:3000)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:1424)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:1398)
        at com.beproject.sharepixel.CameraFragment.capturePhoto(CameraFragment.java:136)
        at com.beproject.sharepixel.CameraFragment.access$000(CameraFragment.java:32)
        at com.beproject.sharepixel.CameraFragment$1$1.onClick(CameraFragment.java:94)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1137)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1164)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3132)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4047)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48990967/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-pictures-picfolde
```

Comment: The `support-v4` edition of `FileProvider` was replaced by [the AndroidX edition of `FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) a few years ago. You will need to use that. I cover the AndroidX edition of `FileProvider` in [this section](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-files-005.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack).